# perform LIKE search with entity framework and npgsql

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

How can I perform a LIKE search with entity framework 6 and npgsql?

I tried

**1. SQLMethods.Like**

```
queryable.Where(entity => SqlMethods.Like(entity.Name, "%EW%6%"));
```

but I got the message

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

**2. linq extension method**

Then I tried the linq extension method `WhereLike` from this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153779/1489968

It's working, but not for all cases, because it's cutting the search string into several pieces.

```
queryable.WhereLike(t => t.Name, "%EW%6%"));
```

is transformed into two and-connected `Contains` calls, that are transformed into two `LIKE` expressions.

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE ... AND 
("Extent1"."name" LIKE E'%EU%' AND "Extent1"."name" LIKE E'%6%')
```

which means *"All entities with the name containing 'EU' and '6'"*

But I want the transformation to result in a query like the following one:

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE ... AND
("Extent1"."name" LIKE E'%EW%6%')
```

which means *"All entities with the name containing 'EU' followed by a string, that contains '6'"*

Comment: Not 100% sure about this, but I think it would need some specific support in the Npgsql EF6 provider which is currently not there. Could you please open an issue about this (github.com/npgsql/npgsql)? Not sure we'll get around to this soon though...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same goal using Regex.IsMatch().

E.g. one of the unit tests from [Npgql repository](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/6ce6bacbe1dbf9b11314d26f87b1ff93f675b1b6/test/EntityFramework7.Npgsql.FunctionalTests/QueryNpgsqlTest.cs):

```
[Fact]
public virtual void Regex_IsMatchOptionsNone()
{
    AssertQuery<Customer>(
        cs => cs.Where(c => Regex.IsMatch(c.CompanyName, "^A", RegexOptions.None)),
        entryCount: 4);
    Assert.Contains("WHERE \"c\".\"CompanyName\" ~ ('(?p)' || '^A')", Sql);
}
```

So I believe in your case it would look something like this:

```
var pattern = ".*" + Regex.Escape("EW") + ".*" + Regex.Escape("6") + ".*";
queryable.Where(t => Regex.IsMatch(t.Name, pattern));
```

Comment: The tests are in the `EntityFramework7` folder. I assume this feature is only supported, if you use EF7, or!?

Comment: Yeah, the regex mapping is a feature implement only in the (experimental) EF7 provider.